# Using environment variable in JDBC URL (HSQLDB)

Tags: jdbc, netbeans, environment-variables, hsqldb, ireport

I am trying to connect Netbeans' iReport plugin with my HSQLDB database so i can build my report against its data.  My JavaFX application is Spring-Boot based and perfectly happily uses the following connection string :

```
jdbc:hsqldb:db/TFH
```

I use an environment variable set to the path of my working directory for things such as the Spring application.properties file, like this :

```
@PropertySource("file:${TFH_HOME}/config.properties")
```

My issue is that iReport can't use the same connection string because it literally looks for the db folder in the Netbeans install directory.  My idea would be to put the environment variable in the JDBC connection string directly but i can't seem to get this working.  I have looked around for the right syntax but nothing seems to work.  I tried this :

```
jdbc:hsqldb:${TFH_HOME}/db/TFH
```

This makes iReport literally search for the DB file in this non-existent folder :

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\${TFH_HOME}\db\
```

How can you make a JDBC URL include an environment variable and make it search for the DB in a relative path?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on how or where you are retrieving the JDBC url. The interpolation in `@PropertySource` is a Spring specific feature. You will need to provide more context.

Comment: Like i said, i'm trying to make the URL in iReport point to the correct path.  By default it's looking in the install directory of Netbeans which is the Netbeans classpath but i need it to look at my project directory, hence trying to plug the environment variable i'm already using for a similar purpose into the JDBC URL.

Comment: FYI, i just tried with the full path and it works.  I just need to know how to put an environment variable in there (which contains the path).

Comment: **How** are you currently obtaining that URL. I repeat my previous comment: The interpolation in @PropertySource is a Spring specific feature. So if you just construct a normal string it is not going to work.

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure i understand your question.  I am typing the URL myself into the iReport plugin in Netbeans so i can construct a report.  It's the same DB as the app uses and i'm later going to programatically provide the datasource but for now iReport requires its own datasource to build the report.

Comment: If you're typing it in yourself, then you cannot have variable expansion like offered by spring.

Comment: Ok so basically JDBC URLs cannot contain references to environment variables when they are manually typed in but if they are populated programmatically they can, correct?

Comment: No, the expansion of variables will only work in specific case where you use Spring Framework and only if Spring Framework applies variable expansion/SpringEL in that specific case. In normal Java code it wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

HSLQDB supports variables defined for Java in this context. So if you define your TFH_HOME as part of your Java command, it will be picked up when the JDBC URL is processed.